# How to include special chars in this regex

Tags: regex

First of all I am a total noob to regular expressions, so this may be optimized further, and if so, please tell me what to do. Anyway, after reading several articles about regex, I wrote a little regex for my password matching needs:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(^[A-Z]+[a-z0-9]).{8,20}
```

What I am trying to do is: it must start with an uppercase letter, must contain a lowercase letter, must contain at least one number must contain at least on special character and must be between 8-20 characters in length.
The above somehow works but it doesn't force special chars(. seems to match any character but I don't know how to use it with the positive lookahead) and the min length seems to be 10 instead of 8. what am I doing wrong?

PS: I am using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test this.

Comment: what are the special characters you want to allow?

Comment: What's the point of the `(?=.*[A-Z])` check if you know the password must start with a capital letter (i.e. you have `^[A-Z]+[a-z0-9]`)?

Comment: Oh, silly passwords :> Just require 12 characters (and maybe limit to 100) and let it be whatever otherwise.

Comment: There are about a million dialects of regex, what language or tool are you writing the regex for?

Comment: But yes, `.` *will match anything* in most regex dialects *except* when it is escaped `\.` or in a character class `[.]` (and there are also some line-ending caveats sometimes).

Comment: I am gonna use this in php on javascript/jQuery, haven't decided yet.

@arshajii That is to make sure there is at least one capital letter, but I guess I don't really need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])[A-Z].{7,19}$
```

I removed the `(?=.*[A-Z])` because the requirement that you must start with an uppercase character already covers that.  I added `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])` for the special characters, this will only match if there is at least one character that is not a letter or a digit.  I also tweaked the length checking a little bit, the first step here was to remove the `+` after the `[A-Z]` so that we know exactly one character has been matched so far, and then changing the `.{8,20}` to `.{7,19}` (we can only match between 7 and 19 more characters if we already matched 1).

Answer (score 1):

Let's strip away the assertions and just look at your base pattern alone:

```
(^[A-Z]+[a-z0-9]).{8,20}
```

This will match one or more uppercase Latin letters, followed by by a single lowercase Latin letter or decimal digit, followed by 8 to 20 of any character. So yes, at minimum this will require 10 characters, but there's no maximum number of characters it will match (e.g. it will allow 100 uppercase letters at the start of the string). Furthermore, since there's no end anchor (`$`), this pattern would allow any trailing characters after the matched substring.

I'd recommend a pattern like this:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$])[A-Z]+[A-Za-z0-9!@#$]{7,19}$
```

Where `!@#$` is a placeholder for whatever special characters you want to allow. Don't forget to escape special characters if necessary (`\`, `]`, `^` at the beginning of the character class, and`-` in the middle).

---

Using [POSIX character classes](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php), it might look like this:

```
^(?=.*[:lower:])(?=.*[:digit:])(?=.*[:punct:])[:upper:]+[[:alnum:][:punct:]]{7,19}$
```

Or using [Unicode character classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php), it might look like this:

```
^(?=.*[\p{Ll}])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\p{P}\p{S}])[\p{Lu}]+[\p{L}\d\p{P}\p{S}]{7,19}$
```

**Note**: each of these considers a different set of 'special characters', so they aren't identical to the first pattern.

Comment: Might be worth adding that in an international context, it would be wiser to use POSIX character classes [:upper:], [:lower:], [:alpha:], [:digit:], and [:alphanum:] as appropriate.  Makes the pattern work for other languages and makes the regex more readable as a pleasant side effect.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler I agree that this isn't the most localizable solution, and I probably wouldn't use it myself. I personally prefer unicode classes to POSIX, although I'm not sure if that makes it more compatible, since it requires the engine to support POSIX / Unicode character classes. In any case, I've provided a tweaked version for both.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is how I would write it, if I had such requirements - excepting situations where it's absolutely not possible or practical, I prefer to break up complex regular expressions. Note that this is English-specific, so a Unicode or POSIX character class (where supported) may make more sense:

```
/^[A-Z]/ && /[a-z]/ && /[1-9]/ && /[whatever special]/ && ofCorrectLength(x)
```

That is, I would avoid trying to incorporate all the rules at once.